# Group columns that don't exactly match in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am working on a query to pull a list of Merchants and get a count of transactions for that merchant. Here's an example (Note: My table has more columns for description, location, status, amount, date, etc, but these are the important ones).

```
TransactionID    MerchantName            

1                MERCHANTA #123          
2                MERCHANTA #541          
3                MERCHANTA #456          
4                MERCHANTB #123          
5                MERCHANTB          
6                SOME MERCHANTC #123
```

Now, I want to group these merchants together but since each merchant could have more than one store, their merchant name doesn't always match the same as other transactions.

The only way I know to group them together is the following standard query, but it's never going to work for the different store numbers.

```
SELECT MerchantName, COUNT(*)
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY MerchantName
```

My goal is to use Regex to replace the store number with a wildcard or blank string so I can group them together by merchant, regardless of store numbers. Here is my pattern: `[#*]\s?[a-zA-Z\d]?`

Expected output:

```
MerchantName        TransactionCount          

MERCHANTA           3
MERCHANTB           2
SOME MERCHANTC      1
```

Is this even possible? If so, what is a good way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option.

No need for the IIF() or a CASE.  We just add a "fail-safe" in the charindex()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([TransactionID] int,[MerchantName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'MERCHANTA #123')
,(2,'MERCHANTA #541')
,(3,'MERCHANTA#456')     -- << made ugly
,(4,'   MERCHANTB #123') -- << made ugly
,(5,'MERCHANTB')
,(6,'SOME MERCHANTC #123')

Select [MerchantName]
      ,TransCount    = count(*)
 From ( 
        Select [MerchantName] = ltriM(rtrim(left([MerchantName],charindex('#',[MerchantName]+'#')-1)))
         From  @YourTable
      ) A 
 Group By [MerchantName]
```

**Returns**

```
MerchantName    TransCount
MERCHANTA       3
MERCHANTB       2
SOME MERCHANTC  1
```

**> EDIT for the ***

```
...
Select [MerchantName] = ltriM(rtrim(left([MerchantName],charindex('#',replace([MerchantName],'*','#')+'#')-1)))
 From  @YourTable
...
```

Comment: This solution works for me. I need to play with it to account for the asterisk `*`, but this will do for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I think that added "fail-safe" is ingenious.  Personally, I've never thought of that till I just saw you do it.  Thanks!

Comment: @QuestionGuyBob Thanks for the grin.  We're all standing on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: @dvo Always happy to help,  Regarding the *, you could replace the * with a # in the charindex portion

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I'm going to need to play with it so I can do both in one statement. Since some merchants have a store name like `MERCH *123` and others have `MERCH #123`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        TransactionID,
        iif(
            charindex(' #', MerchantName) > 0, 
            left(MerchantName, charindex(' #', MerchantName) - 1),
            MerchantName
        ) MerchantName
    from mytable
)
select MerchantName, count(*) TransactionCount
from cte
group by MerchantName
```

In the common table expression, we modify the merchant name by removing everything that is after `' #'` (a space, then the hash sign). Then all that is left to do is aggregate.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fbb2a6ff93e5c601469ecfb720fed4d)**:

```
MerchantName   | TransactionCount
:------------- | ---------------:
MERCHANTA      |                3
MERCHANTB      |                2
SOME MERCHANTC |                1
```

Note: this assumes that `' #'` always represents the splitting pattern.

Comment: GMB beat me to it - this is the approach that I would recommend *assuming* that ' #' is always going to be present, and the primary differentiating factor as the example data demonstrates. If it isn't present, you may also need to include some RTRIM/LTRIM functions.

Comment: Great solution. This database needs to be updated (still on version sql server 2008) so it doesn't support this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using **stuff** and **Patindex**

```
DECLARE @MYTAB AS TABLE(transactionId int IDENTITY(1,1),MerchantName nvarchar(50))

    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('MERCHANTA #123')
    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('MERCHANTA #541')          
    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('MERCHANTA #456')          
    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('MERCHANTB #123')         
    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('MERCHANTB')         
    insert into @MYTAB(MerchantName) values('SOME MERCHANTC #123')

    ;with cte as(
    select 
    case
    when stuff(MerchantName,patindex('%#%',MerchantName),4,'') is not null then 
    stuff(MerchantName,patindex('%#%',MerchantName),4,'') else MerchantName end [customer] from @MYTAB )
    select [customer],count(1) transactionCount from cte group by [customer]
```

[image]